# Drag an image when touched on the object itself

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a very simple app that contains a draggable UIImageView but I faced a problem that the image can be dragged without touching it. I'm sure that the hole issue is from `anyObject` but I have no idea how to replace it I tried `self.view.image` but it failed. So here's my code

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    lineView.center = location;
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: To make it simpler, let's assume you always have a single `UITouch*` object at `touches` (multiple touches are disabled by default for `UIView` anyway). You take the point of the touch and move the subview there but you don't do any check of whether the touch location is at the subview frame. If you add such verification, you'll allow to only "drag" subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a pan gesture recogniser. Add it only to the image view (and enable user interaction on the view). Now you will only get action method callbacks from the gesture when the view has actually been touched, your code becomes simpler, and you can move the view with that position.

Also, in your current code, it's weird to call `touchesBegan:` from `touchesMoved:`. If you keep that code (because you don't want to use a gesture), you should refactor the code that moves the view out into a different method and have both `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:` call that method.

Comment: is there is any way to add the `pan gesture recognizer` to the image programmatically?

Comment: Not to the image, it is to be added to the image view. `addGestureRecognizer:` is a method on `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    if ([lineView pointInside:location withEvent:event])
        lineView.center = location;
}
```